# 2048Game :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning to write a typical Game (2048)

I am writing a function that tells whether there is an empty grid on the current 4x4 board. But every time I call noSpace(), the console shows the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined .(points to board[i][j] == 0)**

Where did I make a mistake?

```js
function noSpace(board) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      if(board[i][j] == 0)
        return false; //there is an empty grid
    }
  }
  return true; //there is no empty grid
}

function gameStatus(board){
  if(noSpace(board) && noMove(board))
    alert("Game over!");
}
```

Comment: so check what `board` is when you pass it into `noSpace`... its probably undefined

Comment: calling NoSpace() will lead board to be undefined. Call NoSpace([[0,0,0],[...],...]);

Comment: I think I know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Thanks for your kind attention @ Kevin L @Jonas w ,as the noSpace() and gameStatus() is not at the same js file , and the var board is defined in gameStatus() page ,  I try edit from gameStatus(board) to gameStatus() , the err gone and work. Still learning the reason

Comment: In this case, passing the value as an parameter is senseless as its part of the window scope. If you want to pass a parameter do: a("value"); function a(parameter){alert(parameter);} this will alert value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates that the board[i] is undefined, as such when the code attempts to get the [j] property this does not exist on the undefined object.

Either check why the board[i] is undefined, or add a check in to handle a null board.

```
function noSpace(board) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (board[i]) { //!Check board
                if (board[i][j] == 0)
                    return false; //there is an empty grid
            } else { 
              return false; //board is null
            }
        }
    }
    return true; //there is no empty grid
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind attention @ James Amos ,as the noSpace() and gameStatus() is not at the same js file , and the var board=new Array()  is defined in gameStatus() page ,  I try edit from gameStatus(board) to gameStatus() , the err gone and work. Still learning the reason